# End Foreach after X number of records PHP

Tags: php, mysql, foreach

I have the following query:

```
$trabajos = $con->query("SELECT * FROM portafolio ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 4");
while ($po = $trabajos->fetch_array()) {
    $trab[] = $po;
}
```

This query is working fine, but, it shows only 4 records, but then again in another part of the same page I need the same table information but I don't want it to be limited, say I want 10 instead of only 4. so.

- Section Header
- Section Slider <-- here only shows 4 items as intended

Using a foreach as follow:

```
foreach ($trab as $it) {
// My html Code
}
```

- Section Mid Body some info
- Section Main Body More info
- Section Mid End Footer <-- here I need the same information as in the slider section but with a different layout instead of only 4 items I need 10 items.

For that last item I have to open another query similar as before.

```
$trabajos = $con->query("SELECT * FROM portafolio ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 10");
    while ($po = $trabajos->fetch_array()) {
        $trab[] = $po;
    }
```

So I was thinking is there a way to use:

```
$trabajos = $con->query("SELECT * FROM portafolio ORDER BY RAND()");
    while ($po = $trabajos->fetch_array()) {
        $trab[] = $po;
    }
```

That query without the `LIMIT` and instead Limit the `foreach` to only `fetch` the first 4 rows or is there a way to use that query with the `LIMIT` but instead of 4 or 10, say I use 20, and for the first `foreach` only display the first 4 and for the second `foreach` show the rest after the first 4.

The main idea is not have more than 1 query for the same information.

Comment: You are correct it create a heavy load on the server, I was just looking at the logs report... what would you suggest to use instead? on the other hand I think i have build my BataBase in a good manner for a good and fast indexing, I'm using virtual tables. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this will exit a loop, but why not query 10 records, build your results, all 10 and then just output 4 of them, there and all 10 over yonder.

```
$x = 0;
foreach ($trab as $it) {

    if($x == 5){
        break; //will exit loop as will return.
    }

    // My html Code

 ++$x;
}
```

This will work with any kind of loop, you can also use continue to skip to the next pass of the loop

```
 foreach ($trab as $it) {

        if($x < 5){
            continue; //code below here wont run until $x >= 5.
        }
        // My html Code

     ++$x;
    }
```

Comment: I like the simplicity of this, which I totally forgot about the BREAK; and the way you put it in the second code I love it even more... now since this is the first answer I saw and the first that I put to work Im accepting this as the main answer to my original question since this is what I had in mind... but the answer of @JakeGould is sooo damm yummy!

Comment: you could really  spice things up and use a SPL seekable iterator, for your data storage needs, but well lets not get crazy..

Answer (score 1):

i'm not sure to understand exactly what you want, but if you want to divide your array in 2 part. You can use a counter

```
$trabajos = $con->query("SELECT * FROM portafolio ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 20");
$i = 0;
$trab2 = new Array();
while ($po = $trabajos->fetch_array()) {
    if($i < 4) {
    $trab[] = $po;
    } else {
      $trab2[] = $po; 
    }
   $i++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First, `RAND()` is horrible since it essentially disables MySQL’s built in caching with each run of the query. But there is no best way for me to advise how to get around that based on your script’s requirements. So just keep that in mind. But here is what I would recommend.

> That query without the `LIMIT` and instead Limit the `foreach` to only
>   `fetch` the first 4 rows or is there a way to use that query with the
>   `LIMIT` but instead of 4 or 10, say I use 20, and for the first
>   `foreach` only display the first 4 and for the second `foreach` show
>   the rest after the first 4.

Yes, just use [`array_slice`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php) like this:

```
$trabajos = $con->query("SELECT * FROM portafolio ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 20");
while ($po = $trabajos->fetch_array()) {
  $trab[] = $po;
}
$trab_slice_1_size = 4;
$trab_slice_2_size = 10;
$trab_slice_1 = array_slice($trab, 0, $trab_slice_1_size);
$trab_slice_2 = array_slice($trab, $trab_slice_1_size, $trab_slice_2_size);
```

The nice thing about [`array_slice`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php) is you can cleanly select a start & end point. In my example I set the sizes in variables. Which makes it easier to adjust in your code if you somehow want to dynamically change values.

Comment: Now this is some fancy stuff that I didn't expect to get, I just put it together with Ajax, by passing some values to the array, now the user can display more item as the want per section of the page which is not what I wanted, but is what I'm loving it, this just make me re-do my original design which give more interactivity to the user and even a better experience on the site. unfortunately I saw @ArtisiticPhoenix answer first, but I', giving you a +1, Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use a counter variable:

```
function fetch_items($limit=10) {
public $trabajos,$trab;
$count=0;
$trabajos = $con->query("SELECT * FROM portafolio ORDER BY RAND()");
    while (($po = $trabajos->fetch_array()) && ($count<$limit)) {
        $count++;
        $trab[] = $po;
    }
}
```

If you call fetch_items() without a parameter, it defaults to 10 or less.  If you specify a parameter it loads the array with up to the amount you specify.  You could also have the function return the value of $count so you know how many were returned.

Answer (score 0):

try;

```
$trabajos = $con->query("SELECT * FROM portafolio ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 10");
$i = 0;
while ($i < 5 && $po = $trabajos->fetch_array()) {
    .....
    .....
    $i++;
}
```

then, if you want to re-use the data,

```
mysql_data_seek($trabajos, 0);
$i = 0;
while ($i < 11 && $po = $trabajos->fetch_array()) {
    .....
    .....
    $i++;
}
```